# Need advice on problem using TeamViewer to remotely control a PC

Tags: teamviewer

I am running Windows 7 on my PC and the latest version of Android on my Samsung 7" Galaxy 4 Nook tablet.  I installed the newest versions of TeamViewer on both as I wanted to be able to control my PC remotely from the tablet.  Setup went easily and flawlessly and the connection does allow me to take full control of the PC. This is a dynamite app!

However, one annoying idiosyncrasy popped up.  As soon as the connection was initiated, TeamViewer caused the PC display to change resolution and size to match the landscape format of the Samsung screen.  Looks great on the Samsung but miserable on the PC's display.  Moreover, when I broke the connection, the PC display did not return to its former resolution or display shape.  I had to reboot to return to its original condition.

Any suggestions on how to keep the PC in its "normal" display mode during the remote connection, or at least how to immediately restore the format as soon as the connection is broken?

Thanks, Phil

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the "VIEW" voice. There are two voices: quality and scaling. I disabled "auto select" under the quality menu and just left "scaled" active under the second menu. 
This way your desktop will be scaled to the screen of whatever device you use, without modifying desktop's resolution...